# Why is the URL not updated when I click the link for that route

Tags: ember.js

I am using EmberJs version 1.4.

When I click on one of the links I would expect the URL to include the id of the selected widget but nothing appears and when I look at the params parameter in the route model hook it has no properties and I would expect the id to be one of its properties so could someone help me to understand what am I missing?

In other words I would expect the URL to become **awesome.html#/widgets/5** but it always is **awesome.html#/widgets**

Thank you!

This is my ember code:

```
window.Awesome = Ember.Application.create();

Awesome.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("awesome", {path: "/"}, function(){
        this.route('login');
    });
    this.resource("widgets", function () {
        this.resource('widget', { path: '/:widgetId' }, function () {
            this.route('general', { path: 'info' });
            this.route('configuration');
            this.route('operations');
        })
    });
});


Awesome.WidgetsRoute = Awesome.AuthenticationRoute.extend({
    model: function(){
        //TODO: Call a service to get the model.
        return { widgets: [{ widgetId: 1, widgetName: "Great Widget" }, { widgetId: 2, widgetName: "Fantastic Widget" }, { widgetId: 3, widgetName: "Brutal Widget" }] };
    }
});

Awesome.WidgetIndexRoute = Awesome.AuthenticationRoute.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        var receivedWidgetId = params.widgetId;
        return { widgetName: "Hardcoded Widget", widgetId: receivedWidgetId };
    }
});
```

These are the templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="widgets">
    <section class="span3 left-section">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-justified registration-actions-menu">
            <button id="createNewWidget" class="btn btn-link">Create New Widget</button>
            <button id="joinWidgetTeam" class="btn btn-link">Join Widget Team</button>
        </div>
        <div class="registered-widgets-menu">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                {{#each widget in widgets}}
                    {{#link-to 'widget' widget class="btn btn-link"}}{{widget.widgetName}}{{/link-to}}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="span8">
        {{outlet}}
    </section>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="widget">
    <div id="widgetOptions">
        <!-- TODO: Change the anchors for handlebars link-to helpers. -->
        <h1>{{widgetName}}</h1> <h5>{{widgetId}}</h5>
        <ul id="widgetNavigation">
            <li><a href="#">Widget Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Widget Configuration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Widget Operations</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="widgetContent">
        <!-- TODO: Design some awesome widget content. -->
        Some awesome widget content
    </div>
</script>
```

I also have an authentication route from which the other routes inherit. Even though I don't believe it has something to do with the issue I'll include just in case I am wrong.

```
Awesome.AuthenticationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function(transition){
        if(!Awesome.get('loggedUser')){
            this.redirectToLogin(transition);
        }
    },

    redirectToLogin: function(transition) {
        var loginController = this.controllerFor('awesome.login');
        loginController.set('attemptedTransition', transition);
        this.transitionTo('awesome.login');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's totally working to me, when you click on one of the widgets

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mohex/1

Additionally it looks like you're mixing up the WidgetIndexRoute and WidgetRoute.  The `widget` resource should be displayed like this (though this is unrelated to the issue you're describing)

```
Awesome.WidgetRoute = Awesome.AuthenticationRoute.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        var receivedWidgetId = params.widgetId;
        return { widgetName: "Hardcoded Widget", widgetId: receivedWidgetId };
    }
});
```

Comment: I swear I was using "WidgetRoute" before and it would not get there until I added the index, I been trying so many things and I am so confused about the different options in the routes that I have no idea at what point I broke it. Went back to a very old version, removed the "Index" part from the route name and not only the URL was correct but it did execute the model hook this time. I am determined to become proficient in ember but it is driving me crazy :( Thank you!